# How to create a visual flow with auto close?

Tags: visual-workflow

I need to create a simple Visual Flow process that updates a check box on the record.
It's displayed on the Lightning page if the CB is unchecked.

Once I run the flow, the CB is checked, but than I want to VF to close, and not show me the 'Flow Finished' button.

[image]

Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

The way I have handled this in the past is with a redirect at the end of the flow, see https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_finish_override.htm&type=5

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.